# Swap array of objects sequence flow

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have the following array of nodes, this are sequence flows that points to a specific source and target. Heres a visual to better understand.

[image: original array state]

The code below is an array that contains both source and target within the object:

```
var sequence = [];
    sequence[0] = {source : "start", target: "process1"};
    sequence[1] = {source : "nav", target: "process1"};
    sequence[2] = {source : "process1", target: "process2"};
    sequence[3] = {source : "process2", target: "process3"};
    sequence[4] = {source : "process3", target: "end"};
```

I want to swap or rearrange it it the and point it to its associated source and target, for example:

[image: rearranged array]

```
    sequence[0] = {source : "start", target: "process2"}; // now pointing on process 2
    sequence[1] = {source : "nav", target: "process2"}; // now pointing on process 2
    sequence[2] = {source : "process2", target: "process1"}; 
    sequence[3] = {source : "process1", target: "process3"};
    sequence[4] = {source : "process3", target: "end"};
```

Does anyone know the best algorithm for this? TIA

Comment: So you just want to exchange processes, and rearrange the relations in other sequences index?

Comment: This is not a linked list, I've removed the tag

Comment: Yup, thats correct

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just want to swap "process1" and "process2" in each property of each array element? Here's one very simple way to do it. Note that I've put swapProcesses as an independent function so you can apply this swapping to any pair of your processes.

```js
var sequence = [];
    sequence[0] = {source : "start", target: "process1"};
    sequence[1] = {source : "nav", target: "process1"};
    sequence[2] = {source : "process1", target: "process2"};
    sequence[3] = {source : "process2", target: "process3"};
    sequence[4] = {source : "process3", target: "end"};

console.log("before:", sequence);

const swapProcesses = (process1, process2) => (process) => {
  switch(process) {
    case process1:
      return process2;
    case process2:
      return process1;
    default:
      return process;
  }
};

const swap1and2 = swapProcesses("process1", "process2");
sequence.forEach(obj => {
  obj.source = swap1and2(obj.source);
  obj.target = swap1and2(obj.target);
});
console.log("after:", sequence);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. Iterate each sequence step using `forEach()` and check if there is a process you want to exchange. If so, just exchange it with the other process. Do this for the `source` and `target` key:

```js
var sequence = [];
    sequence[0] = {source : "start", target: "process1"};
    sequence[1] = {source : "nav", target: "process1"};
    sequence[2] = {source : "process1", target: "process2"};
    sequence[3] = {source : "process2", target: "process3"};
    sequence[4] = {source : "process3", target: "end"};
    
function exchangeProcess(p1, p2) {
  sequence.forEach(step => {
    step.source = step.source == p1 ? p2 : (step.source == p2 ? p1 : step.source);
    step.target = step.target == p1 ? p2 : (step.target == p2 ? p1 : step.target);
  });
}

exchangeProcess("process1", "process2");

console.log(sequence);
```